# Checking data type in a conditional statement

Tags: python

I want to print a character from a string if it is an integer.

This is a simplified and specific sample code which I wrote after zeroing-in on the problem in a code I was writing for a Kata in Codewars. While the Kata is not relevant here, I can't seem to figure out how to use data type in a conditional statement (something like `if type(char) == int`).

```
string = "th3is i1s anot4her ra2ndom strin5g"
for word in string:
    for char in word:
        if type(char) == int:
            print(char)
```

Comment: I think you want [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20isdigit#str.isdigit)

Comment: 1. You never split your string into words, so the outer loop makes no sense. 2. You are iterating over characters, which are length 1 strings. The type of a length 1 string is never `int`. 3. You can use `print('\n'.join(c for c in string if c.isdigit()))`

Comment: when you iterate over a string, `for x in some_string:` **x will always be a string**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `isdigit()` can work, also you can use regex.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isdigit.asp

Answer (score 4):

1. You never split your string into words, so the outer loop makes no sense.
2. You are iterating over characters, which are length 1 strings. The type of a length 1 string is never equal to `int`.
3. You can use the `str.isdigit` method.

Rewritten code with a single loop:

```
for c in string:
    if c.isdigit():
        print(c)
```

As a oneliner:

```
print('\n'.join(c for c in string if c.isdigit()))
```

Comment: yeah stupid me for forgetting to spli!. isdigit() is working now. Thanks!

Comment: @KanishkSingh you don't have to split at all. Iterating over a string iterates over its characters already.

Answer (score 0):

You are partially on the right track with using the `type` keyword, however, if you type in

```
type(<some variable>)
```

into the interpreter, you will always get an output similar to the form `"<class '<type'>"`
where `<type>` is the type of your variable. You can use the practically with this code (it's an example so modify it for your purpose):

```
myvar = "some python string"

if type(myvar) == "<class 'str'>":
    # true
    print("Is a string")
```

now as you can imagine, this program would output

```
>>> Its a string
```

You can make this work with any type by changing the `str` part of the `"<class 'str'>"` block to the type that you are looking for (for example: `"<class 'int'>"` for integers).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with regular expressions, You can import `re` module in Python to use regular expressions :

```
import re
sentences = "th3is i1s anot4her ra2ndom strin5g"
num = re.findall("[0-9]", sentences)
print(num)
```

Basically, this code will return all numerical values in that string

Answer (score 0):

Don’t worry.. Everybody who is a master programmer today was once a beginner and therefore would have had all obvious basic questions :).

You can use, str.isnumeric() boolean check. By using that you can avoid the second for loop since the second for loop doesn’t actually make sense here.

Here is the revised code-

```py
string = "th3is i1s anot4her ra2ndom strin5g"
for char in string:
    if char.isnumeric():
        print(char)
```